# Table alignment problems

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, formatting

I'm starting with the LaTex and I could not figure it out how can I change the size of the first column (dates). My dates are being broken, and I believe it has to do with those lines. 
As it follows below:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please don't post a screenshot of your code; instead, please post the code itself. Incidentally, how are `\leftcol` and `\rightcol` defined?

Comment: please, let code be complete but small document (called minimal working example: mwe) beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ended by `\end{document}`. in document preamble let be only for your table relevant packages and your `\newcommands`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using [this document class](https://github.com/Roald87/xelatex-cv-roald/blob/master/cv-roald.cls) by Roald87? It is better if you post a MWE (minimal working example) or at least the complete document.

In that case you need to edit this line:

```
\setlength{\leftcol}{19 mm}
```

With your desired column width. The class will recalculate the right column width to compensate:

```
\setlength{\rightcol}{\textwidth-\leftcol}
```